# How to formally prove that every $F$-algebra homomorphism $E\rightarrow E $ is a linear transformation?

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory, linear-transformations, extension-field, ring-homomorphism

This is my attempt:
To show that $\sigma:E\rightarrow M$ where $\sigma$ is a $F$-algebra homomorphism is a linear transformation, we show that:

(i) $\forall a,b\in E, \sigma(a+b)=\sigma(a)+\sigma(b)$:

As $\sigma$ is a homomorphism, by the property of homomorphisms, $\forall a,b\in E, \sigma(a+b)=\sigma(a)+\sigma(b)$.

(ii)$\forall r\in F, a\in E, \sigma(r_Ea)=r_M\sigma(a)$

As $\sigma$ is a homomorphism, by the property of homomorphisms, $\sigma(r_{E}a)=\sigma(r_{E})\sigma(a)$.

As $\sigma$ is a $F$-algebra homomorphism, consider the homomorphisms $i_1:F\rightarrow E ,i_2:F\rightarrow M $we have $\sigma ∘i_1=i_2$. Let $r_E,r_M$ denote the image of $r\in F$ in $E$ and $M$ respectively, we have $\sigma(i_1(r))=\sigma(r_E)=i_2(r)=r_M$.

Thus we have $\forall r\in F, a\in E, \sigma(r_Ea)=r_M\sigma(a)$

I am not so sure of the definition of $F$ linear, and I am not able to find a clear and exact definition so far. Could someone please have a look to the proof to see if that is correct? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question; any $F$-algebra homomorphism is $F$-linear by definition...

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thanks, but what part of definition allows us to conclude that it is a linear transformation by the definition of linear transformation? May I ask what is the definition of $F$-linear?

Comment: @ArnaudD. So far, I only know about the definition of linear transformation in linear algebra is $∀r∈F,a∈E,σ(ra)=rσ(a)$, But using the property of homomorphism, we can only conclude that  $∀r∈E,a∈E,σ(ra)=σ(r)σ(a)$. May I please ask what should we do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone said in the comments, a morphism of $F$-algebras is $F$ linear by definition.  In fact, many places will define a morphism of $F$-algebras something like "A linear map $\sigma: E\to E $ is called a $homomorphism$ $of$ $F$-$algebras$ if ...".  So, in other words, it is built in.

Generally speaking, in abstract algebra, a morphism preserves all of the relevant properties of the underlying algebraic structures.  So, a ring homomorphism preserves all ring-like properties (addition and multiplication), and a group homomorphism preserves all group-like properties (the group operation), and similarly an $F$-algebra homomorphism preserves all $F$-algebra properties.  Since an $F$-algebra is an $F$-vector space, a homomorphism preserves the linear structure, i.e., it is a linear map.